# Disable auto creating statistics on table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Is there any possibility to disable auto creating statistics on specific table in database, without disabling auto creating statistics for entire database?

I have a procedure wich written as follow

```
create proc 
as
create table #someTempTable(many columns, more than 100)
inserting into #someTempTable **always one or two row** 

exec proc1
exec proc2
etc.
```

proc1, proc2 .. coontains many selects and updates like this:

```
select .. 
from #someTempTable t
join someOrdinaryTable t2 on ...

update #someTempTable set col1 = somevalue
```

Profiler shows that before each select server starts collecting stats in #someTempTable, and it takes **more than quarter of entire execution of proc**. Proc is using in OLPT processing and should works very fast. **I want to change this temporary table to table variable(because for table variables server doesn't collect stats)** but can't because it lead me to rewrite all this procedures to passing variables between them and all of this **legacy** code should be retests. I'm searching alternative way how to force server to **behave temporary table like table variables** in part of collecting stats.

**P.S.** I'm know that stats is useful thing but in this case it's useless because table alway contains small amount of records.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated description.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you know what you are doing. Disabling a statistics is generally a bad idea. Anyhow:

```
EXEC sp_autostats 'table_name', 'OFF'
```

More documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188775.aspx.

---

**Edit:** OP clarified that he wants to disable statistics for a temp table. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #someTempTable
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON),
    ...other columns...
)
```

If you don't have a primary key already, use an identity column for a PK.

Comment: This procedure doesn't disable creating autostats, it's just disabling updating already existing stats.

Comment: In this case statistics would not recomputes on ID column but auto stats would creates stats on other columns.